# belongsToMany relation Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this models

```
class PostFeed extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        content: Sequelize.STRING,
        id_autor: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        id_empresa: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        path_img: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: "posts_feed"
      }
    );

    return this;
  }
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Empresa, { foreignKey: 'id_empresa', as: 'empresa' });
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id_autor', as: 'autor' });                
    this.belongsToMany(models.PostsSalvos, { through: 'posts_salvos_posts_feed', foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'savedPosts'});
    this.hasMany(models.LikePostFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'likes' })
    this.hasMany(models.ViewPostFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'views' })
    this.hasMany(models.CommentPostFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'comments' })
    this.hasMany(models.MarcacaoFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'marks' })
  }
}
```

and

```
class PostsSalvos extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        id_user: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        id_empresa: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        id_post: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      {
        sequelize, 
        tableName: "posts_salvos"
      }
    );
    return this;
  }
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id_user', as: 'user' });                    
    this.belongsToMany(models.PostFeed, { through: 'posts_salvos_posts_feed', foreignKey: 'id_post_salvo', as: 'savedPosts' });
    this.hasMany(models.LikePostFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'likes' })
    this.hasMany(models.ViewPostFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'views' });
    this.hasMany(models.MarcacaoFeed, { foreignKey: 'id_post', as: 'marks' });
  }
}
```

then i have these migrations

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('posts_feed', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT('long'),
        allowNull: false
      },
      id_autor: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true
      },
      id_empresa: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'empresa', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true
      },
      id_post_salvo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'posts_salvos', key: 'id'}
    },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('posts_feed');
  }
};
```

```
`module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('posts_salvos', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      id_post: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'posts_feed', key: 'id' },
      },
      id_user: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true
      },
      id_empresa: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'empresa', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      }

    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('posts_salvos');
  }
};`
```

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('posts_salvos_posts_feed', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      id_post_salvo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      id_post: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('posts_salvos_posts_feed');
  }
};
```

then i have this controller function

```
  async getPostsSalvos(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.params;
   console.log("req.body ", req.params )  

    const posts = await PostsSalvos.findAll({
     where:{ id_user: user_id },
     order: [['id', 'DESC']],
     limit: 4,
     include: {
      model: PostFeed,
      as: 'savedPosts',
      attributes: ['content', 'id_autor', 'id_empresa', 'path_img'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      }
    },
   });

   console.log("posts,", posts)
   const postsData = posts.map((post) => ({
    ...post.get({ plain: true }),
    images: post.Files,
  }));
  return res.status(200).json(postsData);

  }
```

**I have no model for posts_salvos_posts_feed**

in the console of posts, savedPosts is empty, and i'm expecting it to have the info there is on posts_feed.
i don't know what i am doing whrong, it's the first time i'm working with relations.
*The tables feed_post and posts_salvos have data*

AI didn't give me a helpful answer.

Comment: Could you add the generated SQL to the post? It seems it owuld be helpful to add `otherKey` option in both `belongsToMany` to indicate a foreign key field for the other side